# Calculate sum of weights in NetworkX multigraph given path

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I want to get the sum of weights (total cost/distance encountered) of a given path in a networkx multigraph.

It's like the current **shortest_path_length()** function but I plan to use it on the paths returned by the **all_simple_paths()** function. Is there a way to do that?

I can't just iterate over all the nodes in the path because since it's a multigraph, I will need the key for that given path to be able to know which edge is used. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [path_weight()](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.path_weight.html) function that does just that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I created a subgraph instead of every output path from **all_simple_paths()** and just obtained their sum over an attribute by using **size()** function.